# How do you Conditional Format a field in an Access report related to a second field in a table?

Tags: ms-access, conditional-formatting

First post here. I have limited experience working with ACCESS - none with VBA.

I am looking to conditional format a report back to a table(s); however my report is based on a crosstab query from three tables - Local, HR and Product . The crosstab query is based upon InStock(Product)/Filled(HR) anchored by Local. I would like to conditionally format the report back to both Product InStock(min) and HR Positionallowed. The report should highlight three conditions - Green, Yellow, and Red. The intent is to highlight when to reorder product and identify vacant positions all on one report.

I have attempted to use conditional formatting expressions back to the table but have had little luck.

What I have done so far in Access Conditional Formatting is check value back for Filled(HR). Field Value is >= [Position]![Allowed]. Upon running the report, I get "the Microsoft Access engine does not recognize 'Position' as a valid field name or expression."

Any ideas on how to quickly resolve this situation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot directly reference a table in an expression. For one thing, no way to identify which record of table value must be pulled from.

This is what **domain aggregate functions** are intended for. Use DLookup() in Conditional Formatting expression. The WHERE CONDITION argument can use a static parameter or concatenated variable input.

`DLookup("field to pull value from", "tablename", "field to apply filter criteria=" & some input such as reference to a control on form or report)`

Comment: June7, Thank you for your response. I will work with your recommendation over the next few days. I tried working the expression for the last 30 min but do not understand how to build access expression to well at this point. I believe this is because i do not see how the expression functions logically. Like i said new to access expressions. thank  you again